# $a\sqrt{b+c}+b\sqrt{a+c}+c\sqrt{a+b}\leq \sqrt\frac{2}{3}.$

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c\geq 0$ , $a+b+c=1$.
Show that $$a\sqrt{b+c}+b\sqrt{a+c}+c\sqrt{a+b}\leq \sqrt\frac{2}{3}.$$
My idea: Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=x\sqrt{1-x}$. Then $f$ is concave and I applied Jensen Inequality. But I don't know an elementary solution.

Comment: What counts as an “elementary” solution?

Comment: You refer to Jensen's inequality, but here your "probability measure" only has three atoms. At this point, this is a almost direct consequence of the definition on convexity (e.g. you can do it by hand), and it looks elementary enough.

Comment: Is use of [Chebyshev](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Chebyshev_inequality) elementary enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $c\leq b\leq a$ then $\sqrt{a+b} \geq \sqrt{a+c} \geq \sqrt{b+c}$ so using [Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_sum_inequality)
$$
a\sqrt{b+c}+b\sqrt{a+c}+c\sqrt{a+b}\leq \frac{(a+b+c)(\sqrt{a+b} + \sqrt{a+c} + \sqrt{b+c})}{3}=\frac{1}{3}\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{a+b}.
$$
Also using PM inequality (or CS):
$$
\frac{1}{3}\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{a+b}\leq \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{cyc}a+b}{3}} = \sqrt{2/3}.
$$

EDIT: Another approach using only CS:
$$
\sum_{cyc}a\sqrt{b+c} \leq \sqrt{(a+b+c)\sum_{cyc}a(b+c)} = \sqrt{2(ab+bc+ac)}\leq \sqrt{2/3},
$$
where the last inequality is a simple consequence of $1=(a+b+c)^2 = a^2+b^2+c^2 + 2(ab+bc+ac) \geq 3(ab+bc+ac).$

Answer (score 2):

By applying the AM-GM inequality  $2xy \le x^2+y^2 $:
$$a\sqrt{b+c} = \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}a \cdot \left( \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\cdot \sqrt{1-a}\right) \le \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}a \cdot\left(  \frac{\frac{2}{3}+1-a}{2}\right) = \frac{5\sqrt{3}}{6\sqrt{2}}a -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{2}}a^2$$
Then
$$LHS \le \frac{5\sqrt{3}}{6\sqrt{2}}\underbrace{(a+b+c)}_{=1}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{2}}\underbrace{(a^2+b^2+c^2)}_{\ge\frac{1}{3}(a+b+c)^2 = \frac{1}{3}}\le \frac{5\sqrt{3}}{6\sqrt{2}}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{3}= \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$$
The equality occurs if and only if $a = b= c = 1/3$